# Is it possible to disable websockets with Puppeteer?

Tags: websocket, puppeteer, chromium

I am using puppeteer to create screenshots of websites and I want to eleminate all unneccesary traffic. Besides blocking analytics sites and the like I want to block websocket traffic as well.

I was not able to find something in the puppeteer API. Is there maybe a startup argument for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be looking for `Upgrade` headers in http requests. Puppeteer has an API for intercepting requests [here](https://pptr.dev/guides/request-interception), however it's not well documented on what gets passed into that function, so you might have to inspect/debug that out a bit.

In short, all websocket requests start with an HTTP request with an Upgrade header as a handshake of sorts. If you can reject those requests then the following websocket request shouldn't ever happen.

Comment: This seems promising, but do you have an example of this? Websockets don't seem to show up in standard HTTP request interception, on, say, https://socketsbay.com/test-websockets, and I don't see a way to get the Upgrade header.