# Disable specific websocket connection in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, puppeteer

Issue: I am scraping a page using Puppeteer where there are several WebSocket connections. One of these connections represents a video stream that significantly slows down the process (I'm running it through Google Cloud Function, and speed is crucial for me).

Task: Block one of the connections.

Solutions:
a) Prevent access to this URL
b) Interrupt the connection after establishment

What I have tried:
a) Unfortunately, using `page.on('request', () => {})`, I cannot see these requests. There is a discussion regarding this here: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2974

By running this code, we will see all connections except WebSocket

```
await page.setRequestInterception(true);
page.on('request', async (request) => {
    console.log(request.url());
})
```

b) I haven't found any solutions for this approach.

I see all the connections, but I don't understand how I can disconnect them.

```
const session = await page.target().createCDPSession();

const subscribe = async (session: CDPSession) => {
  session.on('sessionattached', (s) => {
    subscribe(s);
  });

  session.send('Network.enable');

  session.on('Network.webSocketCreated', (payload) => {
    console.log('webSocketCreated', payload.url)
  })

  session.send('Runtime.runIfWaitingForDebugger');
}

await session.send('Target.setAutoAttach', {
  autoAttach: true,
  flatten: true,
  waitForDebuggerOnStart: true,
});

subscribe(session);
```

Comment: Can you share the page or a [mcve] of it? It's difficult to write code against a website I can't see or run. Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen I don't quite understand what you're talking about. I mentioned that I haven't found a way to prevent connecting to WebSocket. My 'minimal reproducible example' is just one line of code `await page.goto('https://url.com');`. And you can test it on any URL where there is a WebSocket connection, it's absolutely not necessary to use the one I'm scraping, for example, here https://socketsbay.com/test-websockets.

Comment: That's fine, as long as we agree on the site you're automating so I can write an answer against it. Different sites have different arbitrary behavior, and there can be confounding factors that result in me giving you some code that works on site A but not on your actual site B. If you're sure https://socketsbay.com/test-websockets reproduces the exact behavior you want to block, then I can write an answer to that.

Comment: That said, having the actual site is best anyway, because it helps avoid [xy problems](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676). For example, you may assume you need to block a web socket video stream to achieve your underlying goal of improving performance, but it may be possible to simply block the request to the particular JS script that makes the WS calls, which is potentially a far more straightforward solution to the underlying problem.

Comment: @ggorlen Thank you for your response! I can't provide a URL because reaching WebSocket connections requires going through quite a long path (authorization and navigating through several internal pages). If you can block the WebSocket connection at https://socketsbay.com/test-websockets, you would greatly help me, and I'm confident that I'll be able to adapt your example to my tasks.

Comment: Yes, that's usually the case when people can't share sites. I'm not sure I'll be able to block it, especially in light of the GH issue that seems unresolved, but I'll take a look when I can. In the meantime, I suggest trying to block the JS script that triggers the WS connections if possible (maybe the script does other things that you need). See also [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/4488) in Playwright which is a similar library to Puppeteer, and it's apparently not implemented there, either.

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Is it possible to disable websockets with Puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46607261/is-it-possible-to-disable-websockets-with-puppeteer/47296417#47296417)